# Android Studio emulator error: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 main loop'

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm having hard times with this error last days, does anyone have any tips to try?

**Error:**

```
23.31   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 main loop'. No response for 15001 ms
23.31   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 CPU0 thread'. No response for 15001 ms
23.31   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 CPU1 thread'. No response for 15001 ms
23.31   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 CPU2 thread'. No response for 15001 ms
23.31   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 main loop'. No response for 15002 ms
23.31   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 CPU0 thread'. No response for 15002 ms
23.31   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 CPU1 thread'. No response for 15002 ms
23.31   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 CPU2 thread'. No response for 15002 ms
23.32   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 main loop'. No response for 15001 ms
23.32   Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Emulator frame works but inside it is only black and emulator will be killed after those hanging threads.

**Background:**

> Everything worked fine in last time 6 months ago when I used Android Studio. After that half year break, I opened studio and updated it. After update, I tested to run my old project what I created in older Android Studio version and this hanging thread error appears so I cannot run anything anymore (including new projects).

**I have tried:**

- Google
- Turn IPV6 on/off (boot after change)
- ADV manager options for cold and quick boot
- Reinstall Android Studio (clear user data)
- Uninstall Android Studio (clear user data and manual delete folders from C:\Users\User\ .android + .androidstudio3.5 + .gradle and C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android and then install again
- +5 different virtual devices, deleting them manually and again try

Running with my real phone via usb, it works fine. But why this doesn't?

**Computer specs:**

> Intel i5-8400 2,8GHz, 16Gb DDR4, Nvidia GTX 1060 6Gb, Win 10

Maybe reinstalling windows with full reset should do it, but kinda weird if there is no other ways..
**Thanks a lot!**

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by updating **HAXM**. Hope this helps.